# How to replace stock quantity field with a drop down list for woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The default stock field is a number field.
But I want to replace the field with a dropdown field.

```
<select>
 <option> 22</option>
 <option> 33</option>
 <option> 444</option>
</select>
```

So when I create a product I will see pree-built options like 22, 33, 444 as a dropdown list.

OR

**How can I replace the stock quantity `<input type ="number" />` to `<input type ="text" />` ?**

Answer (score 0):

The Dropdown Quantity Field Template override one of WooCommerce’s default templates. You can create (or replace if existing) the wp-content/themes/{your-theme}/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php file. The following code can be used inside that template.

```html
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; if ( $max_value && $min_value === $max_value ) { ?>
<div class="quantity hidden"><input type="hidden" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" class="qty" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" /></div>
<?php
} elseif ( isset ( $dropdown_steps ) ) {
    ?>
  <div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" class="quantity" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>">
      <?php
            foreach ( $dropdown_steps as $i ) :
                ?>
        <option value="<?php echo absint( $i ); ?>">
          <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%d Item', '%d Items', $i, 'woocommerce' ), $i ); ?>
        </option>
        <?php
            endforeach
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="quantity">
      <label class="screen-reader-text" for="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
      <input type="number" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" class="input-text qty text" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>" aria-labelledby="<?php echo ! empty( $args['product_name'] ) ? sprintf( esc_attr__( '%s quantity', 'woocommerce' ), $args['product_name'] ) : ''; ?>"
      />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Dropdown Quantity Field With Custom Steps

```
<?php 


function ace_quantity_input_field_args( $args, $product ) {
   if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
    $args['dropdown_steps'] = array( 22, 33, 44, 100, 250, 500, 2500 );
}

return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'ace_quantity_input_field_args', 10, 2 );
```

[Source for more explaination](https://aceplugins.com/making-the-quantity-field-a-dropdown-in-woocommerce/)

Comment: Thank You but I mean this field [link](https://prnt.sc/tadcaj)